# are there any special rules or caveats about calling outside methods from within a Parallel.ForEach()?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

Are there any special rules or caveats about calling outside methods from within a Parallel.ForEach()?  I want to make sure that I avoid any quirky multi-threading issues. Consider the following Parallel.ForEach() routine:

```
public void GetGroupUsers()
{
    Parallel.ForEach(
        groups.ToList(),
        new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
        group =>
    {
        //get associated user id's by group name
        userGuids = GetUserGuidsForGroup(1);

        //if no group-users then continue
        if (userGuids == null) return;

        //update group user map
        foreach (var userGuid in userGuids)
            groupUserMap.Add(new KeyValuePair<Guid, Guid>(group.Key, userGuid));
    });
}

private List<Guid> GetUserGuidsForGroup(int groupNumber)
{
    var userGuids = new List<Guid>();
    //do a repo lookup of user guids for the groupNumber parameter and add to list
    return userGuids;
}
```

Comment: As long as `group.Key` is unique and `GetUserGuidsForGroup()` is reentrant then you look good to me

Comment: I would think groupUserMap would need to be a ConcurrentDictionary for multiple threads to add keys to it.

Comment: There are no "special" rules, regular considerations for multi-threaded code apply. Which you apparently violate here (but hard to tell because `userGuids` and `groupUserMap` definitions are not shown).

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any special rules or caveats about calling outside methods from within a Parallel.ForEach()?

Rules / Caveats remain same you need when writing a simple multi threading application. Just that here threads are provisioned via pool, instead of being created by the user. When you call .Net framework apis, you are still calling outside / framework methods. In case of .Net framework api call you just need to ensure that every thread gets its own unique object to make a call (thus thread safe) or the shared object does the method call in a Thread Safe region. Focus on Write calls (which change state of an object) instead of Read calls. To list few important ones:

1. Avoid Race condition, don't write / update a shared /  global / static variable without making a thread safe region using constructs like `Interlocked`, `Lock`, `Semaphore`, `mutex`
2. Try using Thread safe / Concurrent collections, as they do better since you don't need to worry about explicit synchronization
3. Read are generally thread safe, but Writes are not and can lead to Race condition (more often), Deadlock (all this is easy to avoid using Concurrent collections)
4. Using something like `ThreadLocal` / `ThreadStatic`, be careful, since here `number_of_threads != number_of_Elements` to be processed, which means same thread can / will be used for multiple iterations, thus it would retain the local state, which you might not expect, thus it might need explicit resetting the state of such variables. This often leads to issues.
5. Differentiate between IO calls and Computing calls, since `Parallel` APIs are poor choice for IO bound calls, `Async-Await` is a better choice

Comment: I just want to mention that you should run a benchmark if you are going to use lock-free collections. In some scenarios they are indeed faster, in others a simple lock might be better.

Comment: Agreed that's a possibility, though I find a Concurrent Collection as much safer way to avoid developer's getting into tricky race condition issues, which are tough to resolve. There's a trade off and we need to make a conscious choice.